# Solving $\log_6(2x-3)+\log_6(x+5)=\log_3x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

## Solve for $x$

I have an equation that I have been working on solving; I know the solution, but I cannot get to it myself. Almost every simplification I do reverts back to a previous step. Can anyone show me how to solve for $x$ in this equation?

#### Equation:

$$\log_6(2x-3)+\log_6(x+5)=\log_3x$$

#### Solution:

$$x ≅ \frac{3347}{2000} ≅ 1.6735$$

**Note:** upon further analysis of the answer, while close, it does not seem to be the *exact* solution.

---

#### What I Have Tried So Far

$$\log_6(2x-3) + \log_6(x + 5) = \log_3x$$
$$\frac{\log(2x-3)}{\log6} + \frac{\log(x + 5)}{\log6} = \frac{\log x}{\log3}$$
$$\log3 \cdot \log(2x-3) + \log3 \cdot \log(x + 5) = \log6 \cdot \log x$$
$$\log3 \cdot \log \left[(2x - 3)(x + 5)\right] = \log6 \cdot \log x$$
$$\frac{\log \left[(2x - 3)(x + 5)\right]}{\log_3 10} = \frac{\log6}{\log_x10}$$
$$\log_x10 \cdot \log \left[(2x - 3)(x + 5)\right] = \log_3 10 \cdot \log6$$
$$\log_x \left[(2x - 3)(x + 5)\right] = \log_3 6$$
$$\log_x3 \cdot \log_x \left[(2x - 3)(x + 5)\right] = \frac{\log_3 6}{\log_3 x}$$
$$\log_x \left[(2x - 3)(x + 5)\right]^{\ \log_x3} = \log_x 6$$
$$\left[(2x - 3)(x + 5)\right]^{\ \log_x3} = 6$$
$$(2x - 3)(x + 5) = x^{\log_3 6}$$

I know these steps aren't really working towards the solution at points; I was sort of just playing around with the equation. Regardless, I really don't know how to go about moving forward from here.

---

Comment: What are the steps you have tried?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe you will get a nice closed form for the answer?  Mixing logs with different bases generally doesn't end well.

Comment: Are you sure about the $\log_3$ ?

Comment: Mind to tell us the solution that you have ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the solution @YvesDaoust.

Comment: I also have updated the question with the steps I have already taken to try to solve the equation @MarsPlastic.

Comment: Lol If you see you did not need to do so many steps to get the  last step... You could have got it in one step from the original eqn

Comment: I think the answer is wrong tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \in \mathbb R$, the equation $$\log_6 (2x-3) + \log_6 (x+5) = \log_3 x$$ requires $x > 3/2$.  Under such an assumption, the LHS becomes $$\log_6 (2x-3)(x+5),$$ and the RHS, using the change-of-base formula, is $$\log_3 x = \frac{\log_6 x}{\log_6 3}.$$  Thus $$(2x-3)(x+5) = 6^{\log_6 x / \log_6 3} = x^{\log_3 6} = x^{\log_3 3 + \log_3 2} = x^{1 + \log_3 2}.$$

Let $a = \log_3 2 < 1$.  Then to seek a numerical root, we apply Newton's method to $$f(x) = 2x^2 - x^{a+1} + 7x - 15$$ by computing iterates of $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n - \frac{2x_n^2 - x_n^{a+1} + 7x_n - 15}{4x_n - (a+1)x_n^a + 7}.$$  A suitable initial guess has already been provided, namely $x_0 = \frac{3347}{2000}$, from which we iterate with a computer to obtain to 75 digits of precision
$$x_0 = \color{green}{1.6735}0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 \\
x_1 = \color{green}{1.6735161761}6028420105594976526962483014865547809090912454018791698117840074 \\
x_2 = \color{green}{1.673516176124260238848}57028078132556340450344946364614508901732583022202367 \\
x_3 = \color{green}{1.67351617612426023884839162222058963917030308}792976477026920554313588396492 \\
x_4 = \color{green}{1.67351617612426023884839162222058963917030308353547657451861889646281230396} \\
x_5 = \color{green}{1.67351617612426023884839162222058963917030308353547657451861889646281230396}
$$
where green digits indicate correct values, demonstrating the rapid convergence of the iterates.  Moreover, we are assured that this is the unique root, since $f$ is a monotonically increasing function on $x > 3/2$ (its derivative being trivially greater than $0$ on this interval).

Answer (score 2):

Taking the base-$6$ antilogarithm,

$$(2x-3)(x+5)=6^{\log_3x}=e^{\ln6\ln x/\ln3}=x^{\ln6/\ln3}.$$

Because of the irrational exponent, there is no closed-form solution and you need to use a numerical method.

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the fun of it !*

Since heropup already gave the answer, let us do the same using **one single** iteration using  [high order methods](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.html) with $x_0 = \frac{3347}{2000}$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_1 & \text{Method} \\
 1 & \color{blue}{1.67351617}525914512770936502001715480227532437 & \text{Newton} \\
 2 & \color{blue}{1.6735161761242}2229623976832154151388262101881 & \text{Halley}\\
 3 & \color{blue}{1.67351617612426023}725117282565297065627253993 & \text{Householder}\\
 4 & \color{blue}{1.6735161761242602388483}2362357774862967541409 & \text{no name}\\
 5 & \color{blue}{1.6735161761242602388483916}1928419708807692011 & \text{no name}\\
 6 & \color{blue}{1.673516176124260238848391622220}46176652833341 & \text{no name}\\
 7 & \color{blue}{1.67351617612426023884839162222058963}357352924 & \text{no name}\\
 8 & \color{blue}{1.673516176124260238848391622220589639170}05729 & \text{no name}
\end{array}
\right)$$